# Custom attribute without database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model.

```
class Model_a < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I have one controller, where I want return all models and add one custom attribute to one json, for example:

```
class A_Controller < ApplicationController
  def index
    @a_s = Model_a.all
    @a_s[0].custom_attribute = 777  # How I can do that???
    json_response(@a_s)
  end
end
```

But when I do that, I have the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `custom_attribute=' for #<Model_a:0x00000234deda85f8>):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ActiveModel::Attributes API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Attributes/ClassMethods.html)

```
class ModelA < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :custom_attribute, :integer
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you got custom_attribute included in your database?

Could use `@a_s[0].update({custom_attribute: 77})`